# Mix of columns in excel to one colum with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, multiple-columns, multi-index

I have to import this Excel in code and I would like to unify the multi-index in a single column. I would like to delete the unnamed columns and unify everything into one. I don't know if it's possible.

[image: Excel table]

I have tried the following and it imports, but the output is not as expected. I add the code here too

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

macro = pd.read_excel(nameExcel, sheet_name=nameSheet, skiprows=3, header=[1,3,4])
macro = macro[macro.columns[1:]]
macro
```

[image: Code tried]

Comment: that's not really a valid multi index, you've got a mix of of levels you'll need to either to write a fix in Python or change the header structure in Excel

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have corrected the title and the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to solve it is to save another header of the same length as the previous header.

```
cols = [...]
if len(df1.columns) == len(cols):
   df1.columns = cols
else:
   print("error")
```